# How can I make a form the does not send empty parameters in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, get

I'm using ASP.net MVC5 and I have just created a simple search form. Upon submitting, the controller is called with GET parameters.

The thing is that all parameters are sent regardless if the user has filled it resulting in an ugly & bigger URL that is needed.

So, what needs to be done in order that the form won't send null/empty fields?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to answer this, but probably the most simplistic is to use jQuery to delete Input elements that are blank before submit.  I want to understand why you care what the URL looks like and why you are using GET instead of POST?

Comment: I'm using GET because I want people to be able to share their set of results.
I guess JQuery is a possibility. I just though there would be a more built approach to forms.